# Position / lot size based on buy entry and stop gap

Tags: python, position, trading

I'm trying to code in Python my lot size based on a positive order signal.
Below is the expected output which was done in excel. 
The logic is: 
Lot_size = IF (Order_Signal=1, then Prior_Period_Portfolio_Value * Risk_pct / Stop_gap, 
elif(Active=0, 0, prior period lot size))    risk_pct=0.02

I'm having a having a hard time to reproduce this in excel, specifically the last component where it refers to the prior period lot size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you store these data in Python. But for simplicity I'll assume each variable is in its own list.

```py
order_signal = [0,0,...-1,0]
stop_gap = [0.44,1.13,...1.94,9.06]
prior_period_portfolio_value = [10000,10000,...9900,9807.5]
active = [0,0,...1,0]
lot_size = [0] * len(order_signal)
risk_pct = 0.02

for i = 1:len(order_signal):
    if order_signal[i] == 1:
        lot_size[i] = prior_period_portfolio_value[i] * risk_pct / stop_gap[i]
    elif active[i] == 0:
        lot_size[i] = 0
    else:
        # just need to be sure this doesn't happen on the first iteration
        lost_size[i] = lot_size[i-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The data is all stored in a Dataframe called df. I'm working through your solution

Answer (score 0):

What I learn it from basic app developing courses (PhP) I was use itand on game dev fro sorting data in tables. So the trick here will be to create first the columns and then to add rows as childrens.

On tkinter I will do it like that:

1 - I will create a frame extended vertical as parent

```
frame = Frame()
frame.pack(expand=True, fill="y", side="left")
```

2 - I will add entrys extended horizontal as childrens

```
entry = Entry(frame)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x", side="top")
```

In this case all childrens will have same width.
If you want to use labels just for showing data for every child I will make a frame (same like entry example) and inside of that I will add label (same like entry but with side="right") and all text will have same width, and will be aligned on right.